How can Special relativity exclude the concept of space-time for a photon from its framework and establish a sharp point of inapplicability?
From the second postulate of special relativity we know there can't be any 'Photon's frame of reference' cause second postulate says the speed of light in vacuum is invariant in all inertial reference frame. If there was a 'Photon's reference frame' in that reference frame photon should be stationary which is not possible according to second postulate and it is absurd to think in a photon's frame of reference that photon is moving at a speed c with respect to itself. Lorentz transformation gives infinity if we try to put c in it showing it is not possible to measure time and space coordinates of an event in a coordinate system moving with speed c, that such a frame doesn't exist. But photon exists and special relativity excludes the relevant question "how the concept of space and time applies to a Photon" from its framework. It excludes a point from its  framework's applicability on which the frame work is standing on, Even more, the length contraction and time dilation has a clear cut distinction when it stops working, it is a problem because it only excludes the ultimate speed limit 'c', JUST THE 'c' and works absolutely fine arbitrarily close to c, infinitesimally close to c! there is no surprise, it is in the mathematical framework. But the framework is strange when it works fine and give meaning to the measurement of space and time coordinates of  events from different inertial frames of references spanning all possible relative velocities excluding the solitary 'limiting velocity point c' which is necessarily becomes meaningless as a frame and nothing can be known what space-time means to it. Am I making some mistake or this is perfectly reasonable?

It's only a mathematical issue, because you can't divide by 0.

@foolishmuse it's a deeply physical issue, directly related to the geometry of spacetime. Also, the OP is wrong, special relativity does not "exclude the very entity from its prediction range on which it is standing on". It is the very explanation of why there is a "sharp point of inapplicability".

Saying we cannot transform some inertial frame into one that is comoving with light in vacuum is not the same thing as saying photons don't exist. I don't know for sure if this answer is getting at the heart of your issue but I think it is: Photons bounce back and forth off matter, clear as day, and if we have two different reference frames moving at different speeds the people in those comoving frames might disagree about how much distance the photons travelled, and the time it took photons to reach certain places, as I'm sure you know they will both agree on how fast the photons were moving. Lorentz transformation is tool we would use to make my observations in my reference frame make sense with your observations in your reference frame, just as two people on different continents could do with the apparent position of a star in the sky. A person in continent A looking north says "it's so and so degrees from vertical and with a declination of blah blah blah", and person B facing south has their own set of numbers, but then we can make a transformation by our knowledge of the shape of the Earth that shows the star, although in different apparent positions, is in the same absolute position relative to the Earth surface. A scientist comes along and says "there is no way to use these transformations to know what the Earth looks like from the point of view of the star! How can your transformations not account for the frame of reference of the star?" And the other two scientists would probably say "well yes, they weren't designed to do such a thing, and we can't get to the star anyways." It certainly doesn't mean that their mathematics imply stars don't exist. That's a little more didactic than what's going on here, but it is similar: it is possible to send a satellite to the star to look at the earth, and you can actually make a transformation of people on earth coordinates to people in space coordinates. But we legitimately could not ever get ourselves (or anything with mass) up to the speed of light to need to make a transformation to those coordinates anyways, and the motion of a photon in space is simply constant velocity in straight line paths, so we know what the photons are going to do in any sensible coordinates anyways. Seems like knowing what spacetime "looks like" to a photon doesn't add anything meaningful to our ability to model the universe to me! I hope that wasn't too long winded and pedantic.
